# How to Pass value to webview from viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have UIViewController from which i have to pass nWordID value to Webview. This webview push another webview on which i have to use nWordID (use it on second webview).

didselect method looks like: 
nWordID = [[rowData objectForKey:@"WordID"] intValue];

[PDF_Viewer passwordID:nWordID];
// Try but not work. PDF_Viewer is web view.passwordID is define in webview.

Is it possible to pass nWordID directly to second webview?

Answer (score 0):

Is `passwordID` a property on the `PDF_Viewer`?

Then use

```
PDF_Viewer.passwordID = nWordID;
```

Or if you want to use square brackets:

```
[PDF_Viewer setPasswordID:nWordID];
```

Comment: "not working" is a little vague... Could you perhaps tell us what exactly happens (do you get error messages?) or doesn't happen?